# How to add oracle license after installation

Tags: oracle, linux

I have installed Oracle 11.2 Standard Edition on RHEL 7.0 with some other license.

I have CSI number printed on License paper.

Please guide me how to add that license.

Comment: I don't know why somebody downvoted this question. This IS a valid Oracle database related question! Why did you do that? Something apparent to you may not that obvious to others, especially new users!

Answer (score 3):

No such thing in Oracle. The installed software does not need any license authorization.

The CSI number is used for contacting support, downloading patches, reading support articles, browsing bug database, etc.

Go to http://support.oracle.com/, register an account if you do not have one already, log in, and add the CSI to your account.

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to learn how to manage Oracle databases, they can download and install the software and use every feature. It is only if someone wants to use the software in a commercial sense that they need to pay for the features that they use. Oracle lets you use all the features that you want, regardless of license. But if you use features that you aren't paying for, and you are audited, then you will certainly pay for the features that you use. There is a query available online that will show you what features you are using. For example, if you are running standard edition, don't query the performance views otherwise that you have used them will be tracked in your database. Also don't use advanced compression, since that is an extra feature as well. It pays to know what you are allowed to do.